# participation rate of an advents calendar

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i am not used to working with excel anymore and there is no VBA available at my workplace.
I have a set of data showing a userID (left) and numbers (right) which indicate a day in december (1 = december 1st to 24 = december 24th)

I figured out how many people participated on specific days, but i'd also like to know what the amount of participations looks like overall (how many people played only 1/24 times, how many people played 24/24 times etc). It's mostly a fun project for work where not much of excel analysis is being done, that's why i'm asking here. Thanks in advance!

[image]

I tried a combination of COUNTIF with FREQUENCY but i couldn't figure it out on my own

Answer (score 2):

What about inserting a pivot table?

You can have a look at my example here:

[image]

By clicking on the right-arrow (see green rectangle), you can change the properties of the "summing" field and turn it into a "counting" field:

[image]

Comment: i like the idea, the only issue i encountered is that with your method it adds up the values from 1-24 for everyone. since those numbers represent dates i'd want it to only count the cell and not the value (in your example i'd want to see a "3" as the output for user c instead of seeing the "12". Thanks for your idea!

Comment: @user21026227: I've added an additional screenshot to my answer: as you see you can count instead of taking the sum.

Comment: this is the perfect solution for my problem, thank you so much for coming back to it!